# Need help on a specific Regex

Tags: regex, xsd

I want to validate an attribute of an xml file with an XSD file. This attribute must contain a list of comma-separated languages, like this :

```
<Params languages="English,French,Spanish" /> // OK
<Params languages="French,Spanish" />  // OK
<Params languages="French" /> // OK
<Params languages="English,French,Spanish,French" /> // NOK (Two times French)
<Params languages="English,Spanish,French," /> // NOK (Comma at the end)
```

So i try to write a regex pattern to validate this. Here are the constraints :

- I must have at least one language
- I cannot have a comma at the end of the string
- I one language can appear only one time in the string
- **EDIT : I have an important list of possible languages**

The two last constraints are the problem, i don't know how to do it.

Here is what i got now :

```
^[English,|French,|Spanish,...]+$
```

But it's really poor. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would satisfy all your requirements,

```
^(English|French|Spanish)(?:,(?!\1)(English|French|Spanish))?(?:,(?!\1|\2)(English|French|Spanish))?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gS3iY5/5)

**Update:**

```
^(English|French|Spanish|German)(?:,(?!\1)(English|French|Spanish|German))?(?:,(‌​?!\1|\2)(English|French|Spanish|German))?(?:,(?!\1|\2|\3)(English|French|Spanish|‌​German))?$
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I will need some time to understand it, but it works!

Comment: Sorry i forgot one important thing !!!

I can have a lot of different languages, i will edit my first post.

Comment: If i want to add germany, i need to edit your Regex like this :

^(English|French|Spanish|German)(?:,(?!\1)(English|French|Spanish|German))?(?:,(?!\1|\2)(English|French|Spanish|German))?(?:,(?!\1|\2|\3)(English|French|Spanish|German))?$

Comment: Updated, you could modify my regex to work for more languages. I don't know why you unaccept this..

Comment: It's gonna work, but i got something like 200 languages, so it's going to be a very big regex and i'm afraid of the processing time.

Comment: Yep, so if there's  a way to factorize the regex, it would be better :-)